# java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: wrong value class while setting hadoop and hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm pretty new to Hadoop and Hbase and I'm trying to make them work together. I've built a `.java` and obtained a `.jar` archive without any error. Anyway, when it comes to launch the program I get this error:

```
    java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.append(IFile.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombineOutputCollector.collect(Task.java:1378)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner$OutputConverter.write(Task.java:1695)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
at TweetSentiment$ClassificationCounterReducer.reduce(TweetSentiment.java:131)
at TweetSentiment$ClassificationCounterReducer.reduce(TweetSentiment.java:114)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1716)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1637)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1489)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:723)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

and I can't understand why.

I've already tried some different versions of Hadoop and Hbase, but it doesn't seems to work. Here is my code:

```java
public static class ClassificationCounterReducer extends TableReducer<IntWritable,IntWritable,IntWritable> {

        //private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(IntWritable classification, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }

            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(classification.toString()));

            put.addColumn( Bytes.toBytes("number"), Bytes.toBytes(""), Bytes.toBytes(sum) );
            context.write(classification, put);
        }
    }

    private static final String OUTPUT_TABLE = "sentiment";

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception  {

        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "Sentiment Count");

        job.setJarByClass(TweetSentiment.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ClassificatorMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(ClassificationCounterReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ClassificationCounterReducer.class);

        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
                OUTPUT_TABLE,
                TweetSentiment.ClassificationCounterReducer.class,
                job);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new HBaseConfiguration(), new TweetSentiment(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
```

The code is expected to run a sentiment analysis on Twitter's tweets. A Mapper should read the tweets from the HDFS, classify them and send the results to the combiner/reducer. The reducer should first count and then store them in an hbase table which has two entries, called "Sentiment" and "Number" respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a type mismatch - you're outputting `context.write(IntWritable, Put)`, but your reducer class extends `TableReducer<IntWritable,IntWritable,IntWritable>`.

Change the first line to be:

```
public static class ClassificationCounterReducer extends TableReducer<IntWritable,IntWritable,Put> {
```

Also, unset the Combiner, it won't work.

Comment: I've tried to unset the combiner as you said, while I've left the first line unchanged. Now the error has gone, but the program still won't save any result to the hbase table.